# Bundle.putInt() , how does it work?

Tags: android

I am still learning android and I in a tutorial

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
     long arg3) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         int id_To_Search = arg2 + 1;
         Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
         dataBundle.putInt("id", id_To_Search);
         Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),com.example.addressbook.DisplayContact.class);
         intent.putExtras(dataBundle);
         startActivity(intent);
     }
     });
```

My problem is here I didn't understand how this works

```
dataBundle.putInt("id", id_To_Search);
```

if id_To_Search = 0 then id = 0 ? and id refer to the column name ?

android site explains

```
 putInt(String key, int value)
Inserts an int value into the mapping of this Bundle, replacing any existing value for the given key.
```

as far I understand, if int = 5 then key will be 5 ?
then 'Id' it will be = 5 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) You can share `int` with other activity like this :**

```
String YOUR_KEY = "id";
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DisplayContact.class);
intent.putExtra(YOUR_KEY, id); 
startActivity(intent);
```

or

```
Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
dataBundle.putInt(YOUR_KEY, id);
intent.putExtras(dataBundle);
```

**2) And get `int` in your activity like that :**

```
int defaultValue = 0;
int id = getIntent().getIntExtra(YOUR_KEY, defaultValue);
```

or

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
int id = extras.getInt(YOUR_KEY);
```

Comment: yes I understand how intents work, I mean about bundle.putint

Comment: Intent contain bundle, it's same ! Show my answer for example

Answer (score 1):

That's exaclty what you said

> as far I understand, if int = 5 then key will be 5 ? then 'Id' it will be = 5 ?

So ,when you enter in another activity, here

```
 Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
     dataBundle.putInt("id", id_To_Search);
     Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),com.example.addressbook.DisplayContact.class);
     intent.putExtras(dataBundle);
     startActivity(intent);
```

You can do `int id = getIntent().getIntExtra("id");` , and will be 5